# How do I copy list items from one custom list to another within the same site.

Tags: list

I tried copying list items using "content and structure", but it does not copy the version history. Moving the list items to the new list using "content and structure" copies the version history, but I would like to keep the original list also available.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your list as template with content and use that list template on another site.