# Copying tasks between lists

Tags: list, tasks, task-list

I am trying to copy several tasks from one list to another and I can't seem to find a way to do it. I've seen other questions (like [this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98670/how-do-i-copy-list-items-from-one-custom-list-to-another-within-the-same-site?rq=1)) with the answer being to save the list as a template. I have tried doing that but when I go to add a new Task List there is no option to use the template.

What am I missing?

Comment: With having the list templates, you can create new list by using that saved template. But you can not copy the items.

Comment: but how do I use the template to create a list. I go to Add an App and select Task List, but it just creates a standard Task List (not one based on my saved template)

Comment: No you need to select the template which you have created insted of the Task list in Add an App.

Comment: Thank you, I just found that. It didn't occur to me that the template would be listed as an App. I feel stupid for not noticing that. EDIT - just created the app using the template and the new task list was created with the contents of the previous one used as a template

Comment: I posted few more steps to do the same tasks. BTW you can check those as well. I am sure it will help you.

Comment: Didn't you got the idea from my given answer? :(

Comment: I did get it from your comment, but the other persons answer covered the direct steps for saving as a template (which is the easy way that I think is more useful). Hence, he gets a Correct mark and you get upvotes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40793/discussion-between-hardik-and-ahoff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method #1 : Template

- This method requires you to save an existing list as Template
  [image]
  You can then include all the List Items in the Template:  [image]
- Then (from Site Contents) create a **new** list from that saved template
  *As it includes All Items, You have to delete the unwanted items by hand*

#### Method #2 : Clone item

Alternatively, by adding some JavaScript code to every ListItem (with a Calculated Column or Client-Side-Rendering) you can add a button to **clone (copy/create)** a ListItem to another List.

This SO answer: 
[Set default values in new controls on custom form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154597/set-default-values-in-new-controls-on-custom-form/154603#154603)
shows how to clone within One List; you have to add the code to reference another List when creating the Item

Answer (score 2):

You can copy Task list items in several ways

[Copy SharePoint list items from one site to another programmatically](http://www.fivenumber.com/copy-sharepoint-list-items-from-one-site-to-another-programmatically/)

[Copy item from one list to another, using SharePoint designer workflow](http://www.fivenumber.com/copy-item-from-one-list-to-another-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Also, you can copy list items using Site Content and Structure located on page http:///_layouts/sitemanager.aspx